# Modal popup not displaying after loading Bootswatch v5.2.3 (Cerulean Theme)

Tags: r, shiny

I am facing an issue with my Shiny app where a modal popup is not displaying upon button click after I applied the Cerulean theme from Bootswatch v5.2.3. Below is my code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "https://bootswatch.com/5/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css")
  ),
  h3("Task"),
  actionButton("showModalBtn", "Show popup")
)

# Server definition
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$showModalBtn, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "My popup",
      "popup content",
      easyClose = TRUE,
      footer = tagList(
        modalButton("Close")
      )
    ))
  })

}

# Running the Shiny app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I should note that the popup displays fine when I remove the Bootswatch CSS link.

Has anyone encountered this issue before and have a solution to suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises most likely since you did not tell the app to use `bootstrap 5`. I suggest to include the cerulean theme by using `bslib::bs_theme()`, otherwise you still have to take care of doing some changes. You can use `bs_theme(version = 5, bootswatch = "cerulean")` for this, but there are also a lot of more possibilities for customisation (see `?bs_theme()`).

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

theme <- bs_theme(version = 5,
                  bootswatch = "cerulean")

ui <- fluidPage(theme = theme,
                h3("Task"),
                actionButton("showModalBtn", "Show popup"))

# Server definition
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$showModalBtn, {
        showModal(
            modalDialog(
                title = "My popup",
                "popup content",
                easyClose = TRUE,
                footer = tagList(modalButton("Close"))
            )
        )
    })
}

# Running the Shiny app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```